# How to find if a line exists in the BufferedReader file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have this method in Java, which is called within another method's try block. importFormat returns the class with assigned values (//do what is needed) in the try block. The method should read a file line by line. In case the method call to the method with try block is called more times than are the lines in a file, the importFormat() should return null.

I tried to check it with if block, although it doesn't do much and the ClassName is always returned. It seems the class stores always a first line from the file.

```
private ClassName importFormat(BufferedReader br) throws IOException, ParseException {

String out;
Track t = new ClassName();

if((out = br.readLine()) == null) return null;

    //do what is needed

    }else{
        t = null; //here I unsuccessfully tried to force the method to again return null, no luck
        System.err.print(out);
        throw new ParseException("", 0);
    }

return t;
```

}

I have tried also the br.ready() method, it didn't make any difference

EDIT: I noticed I have reproduced the code incorrectly, I'm sorry for that. Here it should be clearer
Minimal reproducible code:

```
private ClassName foo(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    ClassName t = new ClassName();
    String out = null;

    out = br.readLine();
    if(out.equals(null)) return null; //handle the case where there's no more line to read

    if(/*!string red from BufferedReader.isEmpty()*/){
        //do something
    }else{
        t = null; //ensure that null would be returned
        //do something more unrelated to this question
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Err, so you want to do " if(x) then return null else return null"? Please think about that first. Dont try to solve your problem in code. Solve your problem "in your head" first. Understand the problem you want to solve, and HOW that could work. Then try to write down the solution in code.

Comment: And note: separate your concerns. Probably it makes more sense to first read in the whole file into memory, and then pass around that as list of strings for example.

Comment: If `br.readLine()` returns null, then method `importFormat()` returns null. If `br.readLine()` **does not** return null, then method `importFormat()` throws an exception. Therefore, the last line of method `importFormat()`, i.e. `return t`, is dead code. That line will **never** be executed. Maybe you should consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: @GhostCat alright so this is not the real code, it was just to show you all here what I tried here from my despair... I wanted to express here that either way I tried returning/passing null, it always gives me a valid data from the first line. Even if e.g. there are 5 lines in the file and the method was called 6 times

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Dont give us code that "somehow" shows your **intent**. Show us "enough" real code and a clear problem description. Otherwise we cant help you. And note: always update your question when you have more information.

Comment: @GhostCat okay I edited the code, I noticed that due to the rewriting the code I missed an important part with other if statement. Sorry for that

Comment: Again: [mcve]. Your code is NOT doing what you assume it should be doing. But you are not showing us your code, but what you *think* it should do. Again: we cant help you, unless you enable us to do so. Yes, that might take time. But you want others to spend their free time to help you with your problem. So you please spend the time required to enable us to help you. It starts by reading that link you were given three times by now. The second thing is still coming with YOUR assumptions. And then: dont just ADD to your question. Throw out the stuff that makes no sense.

Comment: And just for the record: you understand that the above code will only read the first line, and return afterwards? You have no loop, thus readLine() is called only once, thus it only ever reads the first line (depending on how that method is invoked?!).

Answer (score -1):

I dont realy understand your question but I think you should not compare like this:

```
if((out = br.readLine()) == null) return null;
```

To compare string in java, let use str1.equals(str2) instead. So I think you should try:

```
if(out.equals(br.readLine())) {
    //do sth here because "out" exists in BufferReader.
} else {
    System.out.println("Continue searching...\n");
}

return t;
```

Comment: I edited my question and included your suggestion with using String#equals. However, it produces the same thing = the whole method returns the valid line from a file even if it was called more times than there are lines in the file (in which case it should return null as there would not be any more line to read).

Comment: It still hard to understand. You should not initial a String to null, may be initial to  a blank like " ". If you want to find a string exist on a line of file or not, try to use:
   br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\youFile.txt"));
   while ((out = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(out);
    }

Comment: Asign  "out = br.readLine()" in a while loop ensure it will read all the line in your file